# Dynamic html returns nothing

Tags: php, html

I'm in the process of learning php so forgive me if this is a silly question. I'm trying to make a dynamic gallery that looks through a folder(./JIN/snoii/) and produces the html code  for the number of items in said folder. This code I've written isnt returning anything when the file has images(currently has over a hundred) can some one tell me where I messed up or point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance

```
$CurrentViewFile = "snoii"; 

function showGallery(){
    global $CurrentViewFile;
    $galleryHTML = "<h1>Dynamic gallery</h1>";
    $galleryHTML .= "<ul>";
    $folderToview = "JIN/";
    $folderToview .=  $CurrentViewFile;
    $images = new DirectoryIterator($folderToview);
    while($images->valid()){
        $galleryHTML .= "<li>!!</li>";
        $images->next();
        }
    $galleryHTML .= "</ul>";
    return $galleryHTML;

    }

    return showGallery();
```

Comment: Why are you returning the function call? `return showGallery();` shouldn't you assign the returned data to a variable instead? Like so `$data = showGallery();`

Comment: I've been doing that in other langs for a while now. it shouldnt matter but ill test

Comment: still is returning no html code

Answer (score 0):

Your `DirectoryIterator` makes the problem,
Please try like this

```
$CurrentViewFile = "/snoii"; 

function showGallery(){
    global $CurrentViewFile;
    $galleryHTML = "<h1>Dynamic gallery</h1>";
    $galleryHTML .= "<ul>";
    $folderToview = "JIN/";
    $CurrentViewFile .=  $folderToview;

    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($CurrentViewFile) as $images) {
        if($images->valid()) 
            $galleryHTML .= "<li>!!</li>";
           $images->next();
        }
     $galleryHTML .= "</ul>";
    return $galleryHTML;

   }
$output_data =    showGallery();
echo $output_data;
```

If you want to get file name from the iterator you should use like this,

```
 $images->getFilename()
```

Comment: Please the line `$CurrentViewFile .=  $folderToview;` that was the problem. Please try now

Comment: still isnt returning anything

Comment: I think it might have been something with wamp. now its working sorta. im geting a 'UnexpectedValueException error